# Tic Tac Toe game by michael dawson the computer_move function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'll try my best to describe the question, but I am very confused already! So this is the winning function:

```
def winner(board):
    WAYS_TO_WIN = ((0, 1, 2),
                   (3, 4, 5),
                   (6, 7, 8),
                   (0, 3, 6),
                   (1, 4, 7),
                   (2, 5, 8),
                   (0, 4, 8),
                   (2, 4, 6))

    for row in WAYS_TO_WIN:
        if board[row[0]] == board[row[1]] == board[row[2]] != EMPTY:
            winner = board[row[0]]
            return winner
```

And this is the loop inside computer_move function to see if a computer can win, if so then take that move:

```
for move in legal_moves(board):
    board[move] = computer
    if winner(board) == computer:
        print(move)
        return move
```

My question is, the `winner` function checks all the combinations to win, and only returns the first piece of the winning match i.e. a (3, 4, 5) win will only return '3' as winner because winner = board[row[0]]

What if the winning computer move is at `board[row[2]]`, and the `winner` function returns `board[row[0]]` so that wouldn't match the condition `if winner(board) == computer` even if it is a win move?

Answer (score 0):

The first function is checking if the 3 cells of any of the winning combinations hold the same value and this is not `EMPTY` and returns the value, which can be a player or the computer.

The computer simulates a every legal move and see if he wins with this move, and if he finds a move that makes him win he does it.

For example:

```
player computer EMPTY
EMPTY  computer player
EMPTY  EMPTY    player
```

computer will check if any of the EMPTY cell makes him win, what happens when he fills the centered `EMPTY` cell, and thus makes the move he had to do to get to that winning position.

Comment: But what if the win move is at [2], but the computer checks only by "if winner(board) == computer", and winner(board) only returns the first cell of the win combination "winner = board[row[0]]"

Comment: You are not understanding how it works. Take a step back: forget about the code itself. The function accepts a board (`list`) and checks if there is a winner. Right? Then the loop you posted first determines all possible movements (this is, he can place a token in any of the `EMPTY` cells inside the board). For each of these possible movements, he generates a board with this movement applied and check if he would win with this movement. If he wins, he then applies this movement to the real board and wins the game, if he doesn't he tries another movement.